# How can I save the changes made by the user even when the app closes and restarts?

Tags: vb.net, formclosing

I have knowledge of the .FormClosing events, but I can't find a way to let the changes made by the user stay there, even when the applications closes completely, and it is re-opened again.

I'm trying to let some string values to remain in the text boxes in which the user entered them. Example:

```
Public Class PersonalInfo

 Dim Name as String = ""
 Dim LastName as String = ""

    Sub NameAndLastName()
        Name = TextBox1.Text
        LastName = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(...) Handles Button1.Click
        NameAndLastName()
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

So after this closing event, I need that when I re-open the application, the strings to remain in their respective text boxes.

Comment: You can't do that as that is runtime. Look into **my.settings**, you can save things there for your need. There are many answers here on SO that explain this. If saving more data you need to use a DB or write it to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save them somewhere physically (file or database) and retrieve them when Your app start again.

There is ***simplest*** solution saving `TextBox` values into `txt` file and retrieve them while starting application.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'open new file called saveddata.txt and store each textbox value in new line
        Dim fl As New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\saveddata.txt", False)
        fl.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
        fl.WriteLine(TextBox2.Text)
        fl.Close()
    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'check if saveddata.txt file exist and, if exist, take values from it and store to textboxes
        If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\saveddata.txt") = True Then
            Dim fl As New System.IO.StreamReader(Application.StartupPath & "\saveddata.txt")
            TextBox1.Text = fl.ReadLine
            TextBox2.Text = fl.ReadLine
            fl.Close()
        End If
    End Sub
```

***This is the simplest solution***. You can store those values into xml, database... values can be encrypted, and so on.

Comment: Just a suggestion, wrap your `StreamWriters` and `StreamReaders` in `using` blocks, then the objects will close **and** get disposed as well. Also **Path.Combine** instead of just concatenating strings for a path.